# What to return at the end of a Backbone View?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm new to require/backbone developpment, and I what I've red two ways to write Views :

1st id :

```
define([
'jquery', 
'backbone',
'underscore'
], function($, Backbone, _){
    var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    });
    return View;
});
```

2nd is :

```
define([
'jquery', 
'backbone',
'underscore'
], function($, Backbone, _){
    var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    });
    return new View;
});
```

3rd is :

```
define([
'jquery', 
'backbone',
'underscore'
], function($, Backbone, _){
    var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    });
});
```

Is there someone explain me what's the difference between those 3 way of writing views ?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example will return an object that you can instantiate, a class if you like.

```
var module = require('example1'),
myObject = new module();
```

The second will return what is essentially a singleton as subsequent calls to require will return the same object;

```
var myObject = require('example2');
```

The last wont return anything, I'm not 100% sure but I think its pretty useless.

Comment: As it stands #3 is 100% useless as the "View" var is scoped to only this module. To make #3 useful, you need to attach View to a global: `window.View = ... `